# Need to create a model to identify patterns in user details

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model, natural-language

I'm trying to create a model where I can detect fraudulent customers who try to access a certain app, using their personal details like fist name, last name, email and username. From the data that I have created, I've identified a pattern where the fraud customers use when they create their username or email along with their names, but I do that manually by going through the list. I need to create a model which identifies the pattern.

[image: Example data]

I decided to use NLP with character level tokenizing so that I could concatenate all four columns and try to identify a pattern with the characters since it cannot be done with word tokenizer.

Is there any suggestions or examples where I can refer for me to get a good approach ?

Comment: Just to clarify: in your example, these are fictional data that you made up? In that case, it would be best to use en email like @example.com to avoid listing any real email addresses. Also, you say you have identified a pattern, isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Fato39 I have recognized the pattern manually, i need a guidance for creating a model where it can identify a pattern in those given data

Comment: @pooza you really need to remove those email addresses ASAP. If they're not "real" email addresses then you should make that clear ASAP

Comment: @jcken they are sample data, not real ones